# Is there a benefit for functions to take in a forwarding reference to a range instead of a view?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, std-ranges

Pre-C++20, it is necessary to use forwarding references in template functions when a `std::ranges::range` is expected as a parameter.  Since concepts are available in C++20, it is now possible to pass a `std::ranges::view` by value to a generic function.  Per the standard, a view is a range.

Consider the following code.

```
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

template <std::ranges::range Range>
void fn1(Range range)   // intentionally not a forwarding reference
{
    for (auto& elem : range) {
        ++elem;
    }
}

template <std::ranges::view View>
void fn2(View view)
{
    for (auto& elem : view) {
        ++elem;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{1,2,3};
    fn1(v); // doesn't increment, since a copy of 'v' is used in 'fn1'.
    /* fn2(v); // fails to compile, since 'v' cannot be implicitly converted to a view */
    fn1(std::views::all(v)); // increments, since a ref_view is passed to fn1
    fn2(std::views::all(v)); // increments, as expected
    for (int val : v)
        std::cout << val << ' '; // 3 4 5
    return 0;
}
```

I have nothing specifically against forwarding references.  One can make the claim of a readability benefit to being able to directly pass an object that models a range into a generic function (e.g. `fn1(v)`).

Is this purely a matter of preference, or are there other considerations when making the decision to implement the generic function parameter as `Range&&` or `View`?

Comment: Benchmark it. Look at the generated assembly at various optimization levels.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, performance is not the only consideration when making this decision.

Comment: "performance is not the only consideration when making this decision" - Of course not (but it's what most people seem to consider most important). There's also the size of the generated code that may be important. Energy efficiency. Readability of the code. Conformance to coding guidelines for the codebase. And much more. But how can we tell what's important to you?

Comment: What "*other considerations*" are important to you?

Comment: I don't have any unique or special considerations.  I make policy decisions for a 1M+ line code base.  I am keen on moving the team away from naked 'auto' and non-constrained template parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are basically several ways that you could conceive of declaring an algorithm that takes some kind of range:

- constrain on `range` vs constrain on `view`
- take by `T&&`, `T const&`, `T&`, or `T`

That cartesian product gives you 8 options to consider.

The problem with `T const&`, even for non-mutating algorithms, is that we have non-const-iterable ranges (`range<R>` doesn't necessitate `range<R const>`). There may a hypothetical alternative design where `view` actually requires const-iteration, but that's not the design we have. So while `T const&` seems like the obviously right choice for non-mutating algorithms, it ends up limiting functionality a lot.

The problem with `T&` is that Ranges leads to many situations of having rvalue ranges, and taking a `T&` would prevent users from writing `algo(r | views::transform(f))` -- and it's basically the selling point of the library to be able to write that.

That leaves `T` and `T&&`.

By-value range -- `template <ranges::range R> void f(R r)` -- is problematic since ranges can be arbitrarily expensive to copy (bad for performance) and can be owning (in which case your algorithm probably isn't doing what you think it's doing -- it may do the right thing for some types but not others).

Forwarding-reference view -- `template <ranges::view V> void g(V&& v)` -- actually disallows passing lvalues, because `V&` is never a `view`, so likewise is surprisingly limited in functionality.

This effectively reduces the universe to two options:

- `template <ranges::range R> void f(R&& r);`
- `template <ranges::view V> void g(V v);`

These do have functional differences. If I have a non-copyable view, then `f(move_only_view)` would work while `g(move_only_view)` would not. But then the reason you'd have a move-only view is that it's an input view, so perhaps `g(std::move(move_only_view))` would be syntactically better anyway. Otherwise, `f(copyable_view)` doesn't copy the view while `g(copyable_view)` does. Copying views is cheap, as in doesn't copy all the elements, but it's not necessarily free (consider a `transform_view` with an arbitrarily fat projection, or just many layers of adaptors). So the forwarding-reference-range version does offer the most functionality, and is the cheapest.

Other than that, these two are quite similar. `f(e)` and `g(views::all(e))` , when they both compile, are basically the same? Which kind of begs the question of why you'd write the value-`view` version over the forwarding-`range` one. There's not really a significant motivator for doing so.

---

The primary place where you need `view`, specifically, rather than `range` is when constructing range adaptors. Those need to have member `view`s (not `range`s), since they themselves need to be `view`s. But even there, the entry-point isn't:

```cpp
template <ranges::view V> auto make_adaptor(V );
```

It's, instead:

```cpp
template <ranges::viewable_range R> auto make_adaptor(R&& );
```

That is, we still take a forwarding `range` - it's a refined version of `range` that ensures that we can actually convert it to a `view`.

Answer (score 6):

This is, broadly speaking, a bad idea.

Most ranges are *not* views. [The `ranges::view` concept](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/view) requires that a type opt-into being a view. Containers are not views; they're containers. `span` is a view, but `vector` is not. Also, most containers *cannot* be views, as view requires that copying/moving is a constant-time operation. And for most containers, this is not possible.

So by constraining your template to `view` specifically, you basically force the user to wrap anything they pass to the function in some kind of view type. This creates a lot of syntactic noise on the caller side that serves no useful purpose.

Comment: If const Range& is strictly better than a forwarding reference, why do non-modifying std algorithms (e.g. std::ranges::find) use a forwarding reference?

Comment: @MarkB Because `const Range&` is not necessarily a valid range, consider ranges that do not have a `const`-qualified `begin()`.